# load jQuery in another js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JavaScript file, which also uses jQuery in it too. To load it, I wrote this code:

```
function include(filename)
{
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = filename;
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    head.appendChild(script)
}

include('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js');
alert("1");

$(document).read(function(){});
alert("2");
```

This fires `alert("1")`, but the second `alert` doesn't work. When I inspect elements, I see an error which says that `$` in not defined.

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: Helpful link: https://www.sitepoint.com/dynamically-load-jquery-library-javascript/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to execute any jQuery specific code only once the script is loaded which obviously might happen at a much later point in time after appending it to the head section:

```
function include(filename, onload) {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = filename;
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (script.readyState) {
            if (script.readyState === 'complete' || script.readyState === 'loaded') {
                script.onreadystatechange = null;                                                  
                onload();
            }
        } 
        else {
            onload();          
        }
    };
    head.appendChild(script);
}

include('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js', function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert('the DOM is ready');
    });
});
```

And here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W9Bbu/).

You may also take a look at script loaders such as [yepnope](http://yepnopejs.com/) or [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) which make this task easier.

Comment: +1 for a detailed answer without immediately resorting to a script loader (which is probably what I would have done :)

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is probably that, even though you include the script, it doesn't mean it is loaded when you try to do `$(document).ready(function(){});`. You could look into Google Loader to prevent this problem http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/loader/